# What's the use of second parameter of std::enable_if?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++11, enable-if

I am confused about the second parameter of std::enable_if.
In using of a return type of int, we can make it using:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<mpi::is_builtin<T>::value, int>::type
foo() { return 1; }
```

But how can I use enable_if in paramter or template? In this case, what's the difference of too functions below:

```
template<class T , 
       class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type >
T too(T t) { std::cout << "here" << std::endl; return t; }

int too(int t) { std::cout << "there" << std::endl; return t; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Plug: http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that in case of

```
template<class T , 
   class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type >
```

it becomes

```
template<class T , 
   class = void >
```

if the condition `std::is_integral<T>::value` is `true`, hence the function is allowed for the type `T` and therefore participates in overload resolution.

If the condition is not met, it becomes illegal and the `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` invalidates the function for the type `T`. In your example, the first method allows all integral types (`int`, `unsigned`, `long`, ...) but no classes, etc.

The second, `int`-only version in your example would loose some information and convert values from unsigned to signed or narrow some values, which is why the first version can be really helpful in some cases.

Note that `void` is actually the default for the second parameter of `std::enable_if`, which is often sufficient to enable or disable templates, etc. as you don't really need a specific type. All you need to know/detect is, whether or not it is valid (`void`) or invalid, in which case there is no valid substitution for the `::type` part.

Comment: A related follow up question, when is void not enough?

Comment: @Rickard The classic example is SFINAE on the **return type of a function**, e.g. `template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>,int> f(E e);` for a function template that is only part of the overload set when `E` is an enum and that returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> what's the difference of too functions below:

One is a template that can be called for any CopyConstructible type, the `enable_if` only constrains it when the default template argument is used:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T , 
       class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type >
T too(T t) { std::cout << "here" << std::endl; return t; }

int too(int t) { std::cout << "there" << std::endl; return t; }

int main()
{
    too<double, void>(1.0);
}
```