# Is it possible for a function to only accept a limited set of types for a given argument?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, polymorphism

I know how to do it with any data type with template:

```
template<typename T>
T myFunc(T data) { ... }
```

But is there a way to narrow the set of allowed types to for example `int` and `char` or `std::string` and `std::wstring`, so the compiler would throw an error when encountering not allowed argument type and I will get error on compile time instead of run time ?

edit: Big thanks to ecatmur, now I understand the whole concept.

```
template<typename itemA_type, typename itemB_type>
typename std::enable_if<
  (
    std::is_same<itemA_type, int>::value ||
    std::is_same<itemA_type, char>::value) &&
  (
    std::is_same<itemB_type, std::string>::value ||
    std::is_same<itemB_type, std::wstring>::value ||
    std::is_same<itemB_type, const char*>::value ||
    std::is_same<itemB_type, const wchar_t*>::value
  ) ,
  void
>::type
myFunction(itemA_type itemA, itemB_type itemB) {
  using namespace std;
  cout << itemA << itemB << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use C++11 features?

Comment: This can be done in an ad-hoc fashion in any of the ways described below by `DeadMG`. For a library solution, see [Boost.ConceptCheck](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) (among others).

Comment: Why a template, **if you can just overload the function with the four desired argument types????**

Comment: @Massa One can use the overloading but in such case a lot of copy+paste operations should be executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution using `enable_if` and `is_same`:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, int>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, char>::value,
    T>::type
myFunc(T data) { ... }
```

As the predicate on `T` becomes more complex (for example, do you just allow `string` and `wstring`, or other specializations of `basic_string`?) you may start to want to write more complex predicate metafunctions; but for now, a simple expression is likely to suffice.

Comment: it doesn't work for me: *error: two or more data types in declaration of 'myFunc'*

Comment: @rsk82 you've left out a semicolon on a preceding line.

Comment: Ok, I tried to correct it by putting return type declaration before the function name... strange, without it it's working... so where I put here return type of this function ?

Comment: @rsk82 you put it as the second parameter in the `enable_if` parameter list - in my example I've put `T` there.

Comment: @rsk82 for ways to use `enable_if`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977799/whats-the-use-of-second-parameter-of-stdenable-if?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

Take this utility trait class:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Us>
struct is_any_of
    : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        std::conditional<
            std::is_same<T,U>::value,
            std::true_type,
            is_any_of<T,Us...>
        >::type::value
      >
{ };

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_any_of<T,U> : std::is_same<T,U>::type { };
```

Then you can use it in a static assertion:

```
template<typename T>
T myFunc(T data)
{
    static_assert( is_any_of<T, int, char, std::string>{}, "T not allowed");
}
```

You can use `std::is_convertible` or `std::is_constructible` instead of `std::is_same` if you feel it's more appropriate.

[**Live example.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/309ab950537360d0)

Comment: As I can see you disable the possibility of using `myFunc` with `int`, `char` and `std::string` types, don't you?

Comment: @Constructor No. The `static_assert` line says *"T shall be either int, char or string or else we die."*

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> struct AllowedType : std::false_type {};
template<> struct AllowedType<int> : std::true_type {}; // Add more specializations.
template<> struct AllowedType<char> : std::true_type {}; // Add more specializations.

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<AllowedType<T>::value, T>::type
myFunc(T data);

int main() {
    myFunc(1);   // int, okay
    myFunc('c'); // char, okay
    myFunc(1.);  // double, fail
}
```

Or you can specify the set of allowed types as `boost::mpl::vector<>` sequence (same effect as above):

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, char> allowed_type_set;

template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::contains<allowed_type_set, T>, T>::type
myFunc(T data);

int main() {
    myFunc(1);   // int, okay
    myFunc('c'); // char, okay
    myFunc(1.);  // double, fail
}
```

Comment: I can't grasp it... now I read this as a magic. Could you do example with `int` and `char` for me without using boost ? Maybe in this way I will understand what every keyword does.

Comment: @rsk82 See my first code snippet, it allows `int` and `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Trait classes take a lot of typing, and boost is a heavy dependency just to get a simple typelist. I'd implement a simple variadic typelist template for this:

```
template <typename...>
struct typelist {
    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool contains() {
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename Head, typename...Tail>
struct typelist<Head, Tail...> {
    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool contains() {
        return std::is_same<Head, U>::value || typelist<Tail...>::template contains<U>();
    }
};
```

so `myFunc` becomes:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<typelist<int,char,std::string>::contains<T>(), T>::type
myFunc(T data);
```

[See it live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03075ac73eddd99c).

---

It would be nice to have Concepts Lite so we can write:

```
template <typename T, typename...Types>
concept bool InList() {
    return typelist<Types...>::template contains<T>();
}

template<InList<int,char,std::string> T>
T myFunc(T data);
```

The usage syntax is so much simpler.

Comment: Why not return `std::integral_constant< bool, blah >`?  Then you can tag dispatch instead of SFINAE.  (or use `operator bool() constexpr` to extract it for SFINAE).  `constexpr` `bool`s are best used when the result MAY BE the result of a run time calculation or non-type value of an argument.

Comment: @Yakk I like the readability of `typelist<...>::contains<...>()`. I find that `constexpr bool` functions provide a very flexible primitive which can be used for SFINAE, or dispatch `std::integral_constant<bool, typelist<...>::contains<...>()>`, or even Concepts Lite, in which this would be simply `template <typename T> requires typelist<int,char,std::string>::contains<U>() T myFunc(T data);` I think `constexpr` functions are easier for most programmers to understand since they emulate the imperative style of "normal" C++ and not metaprogramming's FP style.

Comment: @Yakk  It's a tradeoff, I think one overload with a readable SFINAE condition is better in this case than multiple overloads with tag dispatch.

Comment: Keep the same `typelist<...>::contains<...>()` syntax, but have `contains` return either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`, not a `bool`.  There is a `constexpr` conversion to `bool`, so it works in most cases where you want a `bool`, **and** it can be used via tag dispatching.  Base returns `std::false_type` and `return {};`, specialized moves the logic into the return type (`std::integral_constant<bool, logic>`) and `return {};`

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I know all this. I repeat that those of us familiar with metaprogramming have been bamboozled into thinking that wrapping everything up in types and overloads is a good idea. A predicate is essentially a boolean function on types; why obfuscate it with `std::integral_constant<bool, ...>` instead of simply `bool`?

Comment: Tag dispatching is far easier: `template<typename T> T myFunc( T data ) { return details::myFunc( std::move(data), typelist<int, double, std::string>::contains<T>() ); }` vs `template<typename T> T myFunc( T data ) { return details::myFunc( std::move(data), std::integral_constant< bool, typelist<int, double, std::string>::contains<T>()>{} ); }`, and all other uses end up equivalent: going from `true_type` to `true` is easy, going from `true` to `true_type` requires boilerplate and is restricted to the immediate context where you call `contains`.

Comment: Nice post and I appreciate your comments, I wish I had run into you are cppcon. Would this still be your choice of code today for C++11, what about C++14/17?

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class...>struct types{typedef types type;};
template<class T, class types>struct contains:std::false_type {};
template<class T, class T0, class... Ts>struct contains<T, types<T0, Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<T, T0>::value || contains<T, types<Ts...>>::value
  >
{};
```

using the above, we can use SFINAE or tag dispatching.  You might also want to consider `std::is_convertible` instead of `is_same`.

```
typedef types<int,double, std::string> allowed_types;

template<typename T, typename=typename std::enable_if< contains<T, allowed_types>::value >::type>
T myFunc(T data) {
  // code
}
```

or tag dispatching:

```
namespace details {
  template<typename T>
  T myFunc(T data, std::true_type) {
    // code
  }
}
template<typename T>
T myFunc(T data) {
  return details::myFunc(std::forward<T>(data), contains<T, allowed_types>{});
}
```

which generates nice errors and allows you to write a fallback version easily, or do it via a `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T>
T myFunc(T data) {
  static_assert(contains<T, allowed_types>{}, "type not allowed");
  // code
}
```

all of which have various advantages.  While SFINAE seems tempting, I would advise against it: it is fragile and can generate insane error messages.

Comment: Bikeshed: It bothers me that `contains<T, allowed_types>` seems to be asking if `T` contains `allowed_types`. I think `contains<allowed_types, T>` or `is_in<T, allowed_types>` would be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloading, SFINAE, tag dispatching, or specializations to achieve this. All can produce the result you want.

Comment: And also C++11 explicit template instantiation declaration + definition.

Comment: You *could* do it that way but pretty much nobody would because it's a lot of arsing around.