# C++ std::enable_if - Second Argument's Functionality

Tags: c++, templates

I've started working with code that often uses template features, but I'm finding this part of the language quite foreign even though I'm quite familiar with much of the other functionality of C++.

I was writing some test code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(T arg) {
  std::cout << "Integral template" << std::endl;
}

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(T arg) {
  std::cout << "Class template" << std::endl;
}

class MyClass{
 public:
  MyClass() {}
};

int main() {
  foo(3);
  foo(MyClass());

  return 0;
}
```

which gives the output

```
Integral template
Class template
```

What concerned me at this point was the type `T` in the second parameter of `std::enable_if`, because I couldn't see it serving any purpose. What if I just replaced it with something simple like `int`?

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T arg) {
  std::cout << "Integral template" << std::endl;
}

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T arg) {
  std::cout << "Class template" << std::endl;
}

class MyClass{
 public:
  MyClass() {}
};

int main() {
  foo(3);
  foo(MyClass());

  return 0;
}
```

---

I'm sure it matters in general, but in this case the output is the same.  Under the surface, what's the difference?  How exactly does the compiler read and interpret this type of declaration?

I've looked over the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977799/whats-the-use-of-second-parameter-of-stdenable-if), but I wasn't able to glean enough of an understanding from them to answer my questions.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) on cppreference.com. Also, the accepted answer to the question you linked to is pretty clear about how `enabled_if` works in this situation. If the first parameter is `false`, the second parameter is ignored, `type` is undefined, so the calling template is ill-formed and gets ignored during overload resolution. So what exactly are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can put any type for which you can give default value for the template, so `int` is completely valid. Pointers are also a common alternative (so `T*` in your case).